# C++ pointers - conflict declaration and pointer-to-pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, declaration, conflict

When I made the following declarations:

```
int b;
int c;
int *b;
int *c;
```

I got the following output when compiled:

[image]

*Note: I'm using Cygwin console, that is why I couldn't copy-paste output*

So, do we conclude here that when we declare a `pointer` variable, it is *at the same time* an ordinary varibale that can hold data on its own? In other words, a memory location that has an address and a value?

I'm asking this since I want to try `pointer-to-pointer`?

If I have `int **c' for example, how can I make it hold the following:

**Value of (b) /Address of (b)/Value of (a)/ Address of (a)**

And, is there `int ***c`?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can copy out of a Windows console.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring two variables with the same name in the same scope. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

```
int b;
int *b;
```

Obviously, this explains the error that you see.

How can you declare two variables with *same* name? Two variables with same name cause the conflict!

Same explanation for this as well:

```
int c;
int *c;
```

Two variables with same name, hence the conflict!

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is a variable that stores a memory address. So, yes, it has a value, and a memory address.

`int *p = 0; int **pp = &p`. This is valid, `p` is a pointer that is stored in the stack and has a value of 0 and some memory address; `pp` is also allocated on the stack, has another memory addres and holds the memory address of `p`.

A memory address must be stored somewhere and takes a fixed amount of storage. For example a memory address could, depending on your implementation, be stored on four bytes. In this case you have

- `sizeof(char)` = 1
- `sizeof(char *)` = 4
- `sizeof(`*any other pointer type, including pointer to pointer*`)` = 4.

so, by performing `reinterpret_cast`s your pointer can store any type that takes up to four bytes. But why would you like to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a pointer is a regular variable that has value and occupies some memory. The reason for the error you get has nothing to do with this, though, it's simply because you try to declare two different things with the same name.

And of course you can have pointers to pointers or even pointers to pointers to pointers or even more levels of this insanity. The only question would be is how to use them. I can imagine a lot of uses for pointers to pointers. For more levels I can only imagine an "array of arrays" kind of use, but it's still something.

But what you shouldn't do is to store values of wrong type in a variable. If you have a pointer to pointer, you should store an address of some pointer (of correct type) there, nothing else, for example:

```
int a;
int *b = &a;
int **c = &b;
```

In this example, it would be absolutely wrong to store the value of a in c, although it's possible on platforms where int and pointers have the same size. But it would be like storing a text string in a - absolutely pointless and dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Let's teach you some basics.

```
int b;
```

b is a variable of type int, that holds an integral value, such as 3, -28, 49382

```
int *b;
```

b is a variable of type int* that holds a pointer. It can be NULL or point to a variable that contains an int. Because it is not const int* you can write to it as well as read from it. You can move it around to point to different int variables as long as they have no const (or volatile) qualifiers. You can also use the pointer to point to some dynamically-allocated memory or the start of an array of such (eg `int *b = new int;` or `int *b = new int[N]`) or to a location in a static array.

So b is either an integer variable, or a pointer variable. It can't be both.

To answer your last point, yes you can have pointers to pointers, and there is no limit in the depth although it would obviously become unreadable to have `int *******p`

Comment: So if I have a variable of type `int*`, does this mean that that value that the variable will hold is a `memory address`? In this case, what will the variable of type `int**` hold? Thanks

Comment: Also a memory address. At that address, you can find a pointer (i.e. another memory address), which then points to an integer.

Answer (score 1):

> So, do we conclude here that when we declare a pointer variable, it is at the same time an ordinary varibale that can hold data on its own? In other words, a memory location that has an address and a value?

Yes that's exactly correct. A pointer is a variable that holds an address. In your code, you have declared two variables with the same name (in the same namespace). That it not allowed.